# how to use "BPF_MAP_TYPE_SOCKHASH"

Tags: ebpf, bpf

I'm testing nginx_quic with quic_bpf on, but I was encountered with BPF_MAP_CREATE failure. The errno(22) told invalid argument. I wrote a simple demo of BPF_MAP_CREATE with type of BPF_MAP_TYPE_SOCKHASH. But errno(7) told Argument list too long. I don't know how to use `BPF_MAP_TYPE_SOCKHASH`.

Here's my code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main(){
    union bpf_attr attr;
    memset(&attr, sizeof(union bpf_attr), 0);
    
- attr.map_type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_SOCKHASH;
    attr.key_size = sizeof(uint64_t);
    attr.value_size = sizeof(uint64_t);
    attr.max_entries = 64;
    attr.map_flags = 0;
    
    
    int ret = syscall(__NR_bpf, BPF_MAP_CREATE, attr, sizeof(attr));
    printf("ret = %d, errno = %d\n", ret, errno);
    return 0;
}
```

result:  ret = -1, errno = 7

My linux kernel is 5.4,
uname -a:
Linux h3c-R4900 5.4.0-126-generic #142~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 1 16:25:16 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Can anyone give me a working example or tell what's the problem with my code or the system environment?
I thought bpf filter was implemented in the linux kernel, or do I need libbpf or any dependencies?

Comment: I found some mistakes I made:
memset(&attr, sizeof(union bpf_attr), 0); -> memset(&attr, 0, sizeof(union bpf_attr));
int ret = syscall(__NR_bpf, BPF_MAP_CREATE, attr, sizeof(attr)); -> int ret = syscall(__NR_bpf, BPF_MAP_CREATE, &attr, sizeof(attr));

then it comes to errno 22, same with nginx_quic testing

Comment: Could you share a full example with a BPF program that compiles and the loader you are using?

Comment: I thought that BPF_MAP_CREATE works before a BPF program load. The full example is [nginx_quic project](https://hg.nginx.org/nginx-quic/shortlog/quic). Is ubuntu18.04(kernel 5.4) naturally installed with BPF_MAP_TYPE_SOCKHASH, or do I need to recompile linux kernel with any bpf related option?

Comment: Yes, the map is created before the program is loaded. But the map definition is usually in the BPF program itself, and compiled to an ELF file that the loader uses. Without seeing that loader, it's hard to help.

Comment: BPF_MAP_TYPE_SOCKHASH should be defined by kernel since linux4.18. The map type can be found in /usr/src/linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-126/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h, while can't be found in /usr/include/linux/bpf.h. They do not match， I copied /usr/src/linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-126/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h to /usr/include/linux/bpf.h so the compilation passed. When I  "man bpf", I found that supported map_type doesn't contain BPF_MAP_TYPE_SOCKHASH in ubuntu 18.04. While I tested my code above in an ubuntu2204， the map is created successfully.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is caused by missing support of ebpf of the linux kernel. I solved it by recompiling linux kernel with almost every ebpf related config on. Then it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, it is indeed the setting of the kernel compilation option, exactly，the BPF_STREAM_PARSER option needs to be set. see [bpf_type.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/include/linux/bpf_types.h#L69)